# How does Stack Overflow save and show tags?

Tags: discussion

I am a user on Stack Overflow, and I think every page that shows questions, display all tags and the questions. Are the tags saved in a tags table or are they included together with the questions table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer)

The `Posts` table has a `tags` field. But there is also a separate `PostTags` table with `PostId`/`TagId` pairs, probably for faster searches.

The `Tags` table just contains  the tag name, id and the total count of tags.