# Embedding .SWF into posts

Tags: feature-request

On Stack Overflow and similar sites, it would be nice to be able to embed .SWF files like you can with single scripts and images.

I know that .SWFs may be considered unsafe, but you could have a peer-review system and also automatically scan the .SWF for viruses.

There would also be a "click-to-run" style of running the .SWF, like how the existing script box works.

Comment: Donno 'bout the rest of you, but I've disabled Flash execution in all my browsers. Entirely too many problems, entirely too much abuse.

Comment: [We already allow embedded YouTube videos on particular sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers) There's pretty much a 0% chance we'd ever host videos ourselves, or allow users to manually embed them.

Comment: Honestly, if we *were* to build a way to upload files that we'd then host... .swf sounds like the last thing we'd consider as a pilot. But out of curiosity, uploading .swf would be nice how? What's the actual, practical use case here for embedding .swf that'd justify the work required to build either a peer review system or a virus scanner or both?

Comment: I don't see the value in adding support for a nearly-dead technology. The `sandbox` iframe attribute disables these things from snippets anyhow.

Comment: The only things I want to do with Flash are a) play legacy timewasters and b) figure out that it was Col Mustard in the Library with the Revolver that put paid to Flash. Games, is what I'm saying.

Comment: Nowadays, its pretty much industry standard to disable flash execution on browsers, at least for corporations.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see how this helps to make the sites better.

Flash is considered very unsafe, and we certainly don't want to embed security risks on this sites. Even if there would be a review system or scan service in place, this could harm people when bugs are not made public yet or detectable.

Flash also isn't working on all devices either and a lot of users have Flash disabled (for good reasons). Flash is a dead technology.

Thanks to the HTML5 era there are safer alternatives, which allows SE to safely embed YouTube videos for example (this is enabled on some sites).

Allowing Flash will drive me away and certainly others.

Comment: +1 Chrome are removing Flash support soon

Comment: @Quill No they're not. They're going to start blocking Flash content for all but 10 exempt sites by default. Users will have to manually allow every site.

Comment: @animuson, ah, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What 10 exempt sites are they?

Comment: Hey @Pat can you please use your hammer to reopen and insta close [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159235/how-does-stack-overflow-save-and-show-tags) as dupe of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)? I would do it myself, but already took part in closing.

Comment: Of course. @sha